# Why is my .tfignore not ignoring *.vssscc?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, tfignore

I'm running VS Enterprise 2015. This infernal thing keeps wanting to add my solution's .vssscc file to version control.  My .tfignore has this line:

```
*.vssscc
```

The other items in .tfignore are working fine, but for some reason this one is not.  There are no other .tfignore files in the directory tree.  Surely I'm overlooking something, but I'm pulling what's left of my hair out trying to figure out what.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you share your .tfignore file? I am trying to set it up and it doesn't seem to actually work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*.*vssscc* stands for **Visual Studio Solution Source Control File**

When a solution is added to source control, a corresponding .vssscc file is created. The text file contains connection information and an exclusion file list, similar to the project hint file. This file is temporary and exists only in the source control database.

As a rule of thumb, **we'd recommend letting Visual Studio handle those files.** It'll add to source control the files it needs and leave out those not needed. 
.*vssscc* files also manage the solution bindings, so  better to have them controlled (by VS) .

Also, visual studio can have problems with the source control bindings if the files it needs are not under source control.

Comment: Interesting, was this added in 2015?  I don't recall this file being present before then.

Comment: It had been added since TFS2005, you can refer this question from msdn https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9920911d-1a7e-4ada-90cd-b1b910586cf4/why-do-you-need-the-vspscc-and-vssscc-files?forum=tfsgeneral

Comment: The text file contains **nothing** about connection information, and has an excluded file **count** that is always "0".   Server connection information is in the actual .sln file.