# Difference between .tfignore and *.vssscc for tfs

Tags: tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2017

Both .tfignore and *.vssscc files are used to ignore files from tfs source control.
What is the difference between .tfignore and *.vssscc and when do I have to use each one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34269113/why-is-my-tfignore-not-ignoring-vssscc) answer:

> *.*vssscc* stands for **Visual Studio Solution Source Control File**
>
> When a solution is added to source control, a corresponding .vssscc
>   file is created. The text file contains connection information and an
>   exclusion file list, similar to the project hint file. This file is
>   temporary and exists only in the source control database.
>
> As a rule of thumb, **we'd recommend letting Visual Studio handle
>   those files.** It'll add to source control the files it needs and
>   leave out those not needed.  .*vssscc* files also manage the solution
>   bindings, so  better to have them controlled (by VS) .
>
> Also, visual studio can have problems with the source control bindings
>   if the files it needs are not under source control.

**So, if you want to ignore files from TFS you should specify the files in the `.tfignore` and do not touch the `.vssscc` file.**